# Persist data in google app engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-datastore

I try to store data in google app engine datastore with JPA and I have some troubles.

My code :

```
try {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            Employee emp = new Employee();

            emp.setFirstName("John" + i);
            emp.setLastName("Doe" + i);
            emp.setAge(i);

            em.persist(emp);
            em.refresh(emp);
        }

        em.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
```

When I launch it, data are stored but 2 errors occurs :

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: This operation requires a transaction yet it is not active -> line em.flush();

and

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternalWithOrdering(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3887) -> line em.close();

Anyone know how to fix them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
//do all your persist logic
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

For more: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions

Comment: It works, thank you. But Can I do this without transaction? (Just for information)

Comment: you can `persist` without need of a transaction, but as you see, you need a transaction if you want to `flush`. I advise you to use txns since you are persisting multiple data. In a case of an error, you can simply rollback.